# What is this behaviour called?

Tags: c#, conditional-statements

I have the following method:

```
public override bool IsSatisfiedBy(SourceFile candidate)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Check 1: " + One.IsSatisfiedBy(candidate));
            Console.WriteLine("Check 2: " + Two.IsSatisfiedBy(candidate));
            Console.WriteLine("Check 3: " + Three.IsSatisfiedBy(candidate));
            return One.IsSatisfiedBy(candidate) && Two.IsSatisfiedBy(candidate) && Three.IsSatisfiedBy(candidate);
        }
```

If i pass a SourceFile as an argument that not fulfills rule one, then rule two and three aren't checked. I know that this is the correct way, but I would like to read more about the exact behaviour but I can't find anything because I don't know what this behaviour is called :D

Comment: Pick an answer, any answer :D

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's called [short-circuit evaluation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation). In C# it happens for the `&&` and `||` operators.

Answer (score 1):

It's called short-circuiting of boolean expressions.

See also: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation

Answer (score 0):

[Short circuit evaluation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation) perhaps

Answer (score 0):

It's called short circuit evaluation.

`&&` will only continue evaluation if the first condition is true.

`||` behaves in a similar manner, if the first part is true, then the remainder will not be evaluated.

Answer (score 0):

Shortcut or short circuit evaluation : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation